# Strategy for shard key in MySQL sharding

Tags: java, mysql, database, sharding

We have an existing system, through which inventory is managed. Now the main key through which inventory is fetched/stored, is productID, which is already defined in another system as primary key and can't be changed.

Now, if we want to define shards for inventory system, it has to be according to productID. But problem is that we support bulk APIs, which support bulk read and write for list of productIDs. This means these APIs would hit different shards and would need scatter-gather pattern in our application, through some JAVA framework.

Need suggestions if this is something which sounds good as sharding strategy or could be better in any other way. Let me know if any further info is needed.

Comment: The "scatter-gather" can be so overwhelming that it makes a sharded system worse than non-sharded.  I need more details to further assess your Question.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the important tables, how many rows in each table, _common_ queries, etc.

Comment: Also, what metric has led you to decide that Sharding is necessary?  I would like to dig further into that -- to see if the issue can be resolved some other way.

Comment: How much data are you talking about? We used sharding in a similar situation with the batch insert before but the scale was like 100 billions of rows.